# Are there any good hands-on Domain Driven Design courses?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have been studying DDD in-depth on my own time; reading everything about it and doing some small projects here and there, but the one thing I'm missing is learning from and working with someone with a deep understanding and experience working with it.

Are there any good courses that I can attend to get some of this experience?

Comment: If you are interested in an in-person classroom training, also check out https://www.tutisani.com/training/ddd/ (I am the training provider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dddcommunity.org/

Check the main page. On the right, there is a schedule for upcoming hands-on "immersion" events.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/domain-driven-design-fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your or your company's level of (monetary) commitment, you could check out [Domain Language's training](http://domainlanguage.com/training/).